# JWT auth in cookies with stateless server and no server side rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, jwt, csrf

I am trying to implement jwt in cookies for auth on a single page application react front end which communicates with various node microservices running express.

I am doing this as it appears storing the jwt in sessionstorage makes the app vulnerable to XSS.

However, by using cookies, the apis are now vulnerable to csrf attacks.

Traditionally, csrf attacks are mitigated by creating a csrf token, storing it in a server session, then rendering it in a hidden form field.
Then, upon submitting the form, the value of the csrf token is checked against the server session value to check they match.

I cannot use this approach as:
- servers are stateless
- have no server side rendering.

So I am confused as to which csrf method I should employ.
I have read about double submit method, where you submit a csrf token on every ajax request, and have the same value stored in a cookie, then the server checks both for a match.

However, I cannot get the intial csrf token into the html in the first place as there is no server side rendering.

What is the best practice for achieving jwt in cookies with csrf protection in a stateless architecture with no server side rendering?

Comment: How are you setting the cookies? Presumably one of your microservices has an authentication endpoint which allows the user to login?

Comment: Using auth0, user logs in on login page hosted on their site, there is a callback url they are redirected to with token in url param, which at the moment is stored in localstorage.  I am unsure on how to get this to work with cookies, I considered posting  a request to a server endpoint with the token that then returns httponly cookie, but this seems somewhat insecure to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply don't store the JWT token in a cookie**

CSRF attacks are possible because browsers will send cookies with HTTP requests, even if they are initiated by a script running on a 3rd party site. Thus `evilsite.com` might send a `DELETE http://yoursite.com/items/1` request to *your web service*. This endpoint requires you to be logged in, but because the browser will send any cookies stored for `yoursite.com`, if authentication is cookie based then `evilsite.com` can piggy back on your authentication method and call authenticated methods that your user didn't intend to call on their behalf.

However, authentication doesn't have to be cookie based. If you are creating a client-rendered JavaScript app, then it is simple to send the authentication token as an HTTP header rather than in a cookie. If you do this then it is impossible for `evilsite.com` to make use of your token (they can only use tokens stored in cookies), and you never have the problem in the first place.

Comment: So you are saying don't store jwt in a cookie, but in localstorage.  Won't it then be vulnerable to XSS? Just to clarify, currently am sending jwt in a header on every request, but I have to store the jwt somewhere, which is currently in localstorage, which is vulnerable to XSS, which is why I am looking at a cookie based solution.

Comment: I believe a cookie only protects against XSS attacks if it is an HTTP-only cookie set by the server. In your case the client already has access to the token (via the URL), so you don't have that option. You'll just have to be extra careful to not allow any malicious scripts to execute on your site. See: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/168605/cookie-vs-html5-localstorage

Comment: @MrF FYI: if attacker has succeeded in XSS, he could already bypass every CSRF protection you've added. I'd rather use `localStorage`, be protected against CSRF and worry only about XSS: that's a lot smaller attack surface.